# Can RiotJS be used with other JS frameworks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, riot.js

I have stumbled on the riotjs. I have gone through their tutorial and api on their website. But I cannot find any info on whether it can be used with frameworks like angularjs, react or knockout. Is it possible to use it with other frameworks?

Comment: [Of course.](https://github.com/lucasbrigida/angular-riot)

Comment: Why would you do that? Riot replaces these frameworks. And does it very well IMHO.

Comment: I have any existing projects that use knockoutJS. I wanted to add some custom tags to them.

Comment: I dont see why it wouldn't work. Did you try?